# Cannot create a C++ project in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: unreal-engine4

Whenever I try to create a C++ project in Unreal Engine 4, it throws me this error:

An error occurred while trying to generate project files.

**Running C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_4.25/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe  -projectfiles -project="C:/Users/Zahin/Documents/Unreal Projects/TestC/TestC.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
Discovering modules, targets and source code for project...
While compiling C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Intermediate\Build\BuildRules\UE4Rules.dll:
error CS0042: Unexpected error creating debug information file 'c:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Intermediate\Build\BuildRules\UE4Rules.PDB' -- 'c:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Intermediate\Build\BuildRules\UE4Rules.pdb: Access is denied.
ERROR: Unable to compile source files.**

It works perfectly fine with Blueprint mode, but I need to open in C++. Please help.

Comment: I assume you are using some version of Visual Studio Community? You should specify which.

Comment: Don't put your project file at c:\Program Files. You should not write any files at that location.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Start/Execute Unreal as Administrator. It should solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install:

Win64:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-3.1.18-windows-x64-installer

Win32:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-3.1.18-windows-x86-installer

It helped me to solve the problem.